# промахи в кэш L2 и попадание в кэш L3

Tags: c++, кэширование

подскажите пожалуйста, на каком примере можно рассмотреть промахи в кэш L2 и попадание в кэш L3? я не могу найти примеров на c++, где на конкретном примере были бы показаны реализации промахов и попаданий, я вычитал, что это можно показать на примере перемножения матриц, но как это посмотреть, где это видно, я не могу понять.

Comment: Боюсь что в многозадачной среде это тяжело усмотреть. В чистом DOS (хп-шном или 98-ом) можно увидеть. Или в консольном линуксе без лишних процессов.

Comment: мне хоть как-нибудь, чтобы было понятно, что вот здесь есть промахи, а здесь нет

Comment: А это уже определение кеш. Лучше почитать https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%8D%D1%88_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0#%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B2_(Three_Cs) Промах означает что данные не попали в кеш, а значит снизится быстродействие. Обращение к ОЗУ идет за 2-3 такта шины процессора (а не такта процессора, процессор тактируется более высокой частотой). А обращение к кешу проходит за 1 (или пару) тактов процессора. Соответственно попадение в кеш ускоряет работу программы.

Comment: посмотрите примеры для cachegrind или intel vtune

Comment: На примере матриц - если размер трех (наверно таки друх) матриц больше чем размер кеша  (A*B = C - три участка памяти)  - то будут промахи. Т.к. будет обращение то к одному участку то к другому.

Comment: Не раз видел статьи про оптимизацию умножения матриц. Именно правильное использование кеша рулит. В частности, так называемый _блокинг_.